# Visual Studio with Microsoft OCR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ocr

I am doing a project that is about OCR. And I am using the Microsoft OCR. My request is when I click the "Next" button, it will come out the image that is saved into my Visual Studio under folder `/wwwroot/images/uploadedFiles` as shown as below:

[image]

And I try to run the code. There keep showing the error not found in the webpage:

[image]

Below is my code, I am using the MVC version:

```
<button id="buttonOCR" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:yellowgreen">Next</button>
<img id="myImage" src="~/images/loading.jpg" width="100" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buttonOCR").click(function () {
        $("#myImage").attr("src", "../../images/UploadedFiles/20180627165414519.jpg");
        $("#myImage").attr("width", "500");

        processImage("../../images/UploadedFiles/20180627165414519.jpg");
    });
});

function processImage(thisImage) {

            // **********************************************
            // *** Update or verify the following values. ***
            // **********************************************

            // Replace the subscriptionKey string value with your valid subscription key.
            var subscriptionKey = "*****************"; // subscription key

            // Replace or verify the region.
            //
            // You must use the same region in your REST API call as you used to obtain your subscription keys.
            // For example, if you obtained your subscription keys from the westus region, replace
            // "westcentralus" in the URI below with "westus".
            //
            // NOTE: Free trial subscription keys are generated in the westcentralus region, so if you are using
            // a free trial subscription key, you should not need to change this region.



            var uriBase = "https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/ocr"; 

            // Request parameters.
            var params = {
                "language": "unk",
                "detectOrientation": "true",
            };


            // Perform the REST API call.
            $.ajax({
                url: uriBase + "?" + $.param(params),


                // Request headers.
                beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
                    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
                },

                type: "POST",

                // Request body.
                processData: false,
                url: thisImage
            })

                .done(function (url) {
                    // Show formatted JSON on webpage.
                    $("#responseTextArea").val(JSON.stringify(url, null, 2));
                })

                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // Display error message.
                    var errorString = (errorThrown === "") ? "Error. " : errorThrown + " (" + jqXHR.status + "): ";
                    errorString += (jqXHR.responseText === "") ? "" : (jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).message) ?
                        jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).message : jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).error.message;
                    alert(errorString);
                });
        };
</script>
```

Thank you for your help! I am really need help for this!
The link below is I had researched and try to use for my coding:
https://southeastasia.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc/console